# Set Ninja form input value via JS

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, ninja-forms

My issue is as following:
I am trying to fill a ninja form field via JS, as I am filling my form on several sections of the page. So section A fills the name for example..

I am using such code

```
document.querySelector("input[value=setJob]").value = text
```

Such code is setting the value in the input, but when I send the form, the default value ("setJob") is set in the submission results. Also tried to focus on the input before setting its value, same result

Appreciate any help

Thanks in adavnce

Comment: I think you set the value 2 times. Try with document.querySelector('#id').value = text;

Comment: Sorry @manqlele, Your suggestion didn't work. My code is getting the input with the value "setJob"
same result in my code and yours

Comment: document.querySelector('[name="your-selector-name-here"]').value=text;

Comment: I will try your code now
But as I said in the description: Such code is setting the value in the input, but when I send the form, the default value ("setJob") is set in the submission results

So the problem is not in setting the value inside the input. The issue why is it not sent with the form 
Thanks for your help

Comment: @manqlele thank you for giving suggestion, I think I found the answer for my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Ninja forms has a documentation for this case: https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/changing-field-values/

as it says:

```
jQuery( '#nf-field-' + fieldID ).val( newValue ).trigger( 'change' );
```

of course, change the jquery select method

It seems when updating value, you should trigger change event